# angular.js $http.get how to force UTF-8 encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, encoding, utf-8

I've to read JSON file encoded with utf-8 charset
I use this syntax:

```
$http.get('resources/negozi.json',
    {header : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
}).success(function(data) {
... code here
});
```

But, the response header is:

> **Content-Type**:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

If I try to do this with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "resources/negozi.json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

The request header is correct. But, the response is the same.

> **Content-Type**:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: what's the server you're using?

Comment: As @nubbel said, server response is the one that dictates what is returned - check your server-side code.

Comment: Server side code is me. I write an utf-8 encoded json by myself for testing. Unluckily I cannot change anything on server

Comment: @Banasci If the server side code is yours why can't you just change it?

Comment: If the server says `charset=ISO-8859-1` and it is the truth - why would you care? These things are supposed work transparently, you shouldn't have to (and therefore can't easily) force the server to give you a certain charset. However, if the server says `charset=ISO-8859-1` and it is *not* the truth, you need to fix the server, not the client.

Comment: You are right, while I can't fix the server I've to write my json in ISO-8859-1 charset.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you might need to set an `Accept` header. The `contentType` header applies to the stuff you're sending;

```
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
```

so;

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"resources/negozi.json",
   headers: {
       "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
       "Accept-Charset":"charset=utf-8"
   },
   dataType:"json"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php as server-side programming language you can try to set the internal encoding to utf-8 with `mb_internal_encoding("utf-8")`.