# Angular.js Change Content-Type of GET Request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to bring in a json file using the Angular.js $http.get() function. The call can apparently find the file, but it's returned as text/plain type, instead of application/json. I've heard from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358193/angular-js-http-get-how-to-force-utf-8-encoding) that I need to change server code to make this work, but I have no control over the server. Is there a way to force application/json from my end?

My code:

```
var blueprint = {};
$http.get('/path/to/data.json', {header : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}})
    .success(function (data) {
        for (var prop in data) {
            blueprint[prop] = data[prop];
        }
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('Data not found.');
    });
```

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: The header you want to set to get a JSON response is `Accept: application/json`. `Content-type` specifies the content type of the request. Whether it will have any effect at all depends on how the server is implemented.

Comment: I changed it to `{header : {'Accept' : 'application/json'}}`, to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just noticed you're just going after a static json file. I think you have to change the server to return the correct mime type for files with extension .json.

Comment: Fixed my problem: turns out we already put in a workaround in our web.config, and I accidentally copied it into the wrong folder. \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, when the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) detects that the response is a JSON object, applies [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) over the text and returns directly the corresponding JS object. In your case it's not detecting it, so you should to parse the response by your own. Try the following:

```
var blueprint = {};
$http.get('/path/to/data.json', {header : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}})
.success(function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data); // missing line
    for (var prop in data) {
        blueprint[prop] = data[prop];
    }
})
.error(function(){
    console.log('Data not found.');
});
```