# How to decode into UTF-8 using angular js or Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, utf-8

I started recently to use angular js, I like how it works, I want to know how can I set the charset encoding as a header.

My json file contains special characters ( French language ).

something like : `RemplaÃ§ant`

Is there any way to decode that into UTF-8 after retreiving it :

here is my code :

```
$http.get("http://int.footballclub.orange.com/live/lineup/fr_lineup_253959.json"
})
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.lineup = response;    

        });
```

Comment: JSON file **MUST BE** in UTF-8 initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you initially said, you can add a request header. That way you don't have to translate it if the server supports UTF-8.

An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19358193/2226988) by [Banasci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395571/banasci):

```
$http.get('resources/negozi.json',
    {headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
}).success(function(data) {
... code here
});
```

Also, see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: As pointed by the documentation,`header` should be `headers` → `headers: {             'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}`